# After pushing on heroku my @Messages(value) are not interpreted

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

After pushing on heroku my @Messages(value) are not interpreted:

--> value is display instead of the translation present in conf/Messages file.

I use play framework 2.2.1.

Here is the log of a start and a first display of a page containning @Messsages() use.

```
2014-10-12T05:37:14.320052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-10-12T05:37:14.320052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-10-12T05:37:24.363328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/kosh -Dhttp.port=41328 -DapplyEvolutions.default=true`
2014-10-12T05:37:25.260260+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2014-10-12T05:37:25.672105+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 2
2014-10-12T05:37:27.084724+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
2014-10-12T05:37:27.660047+00:00 app[web.1]: [←[37minfo←[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
2014-10-12T06:39:14.765169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mmmm.herokuapp.com request_id=31eeed7d-0b4d-43ac-b2df-3d142f6db4ba fwd="-" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=34657
2014-10-12T06:39:14.939740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" host=mmmm.herokuapp.com request_id=7ffe7b15-d521-481fb9f1-fba1c146fbf0 fwd="-" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=173
2014-10-12T06:39:14.949590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/stylesheets/normalize.css" host=mmmm.herokuapp.com request_id=4616036b-d3d3-4891-bc69-8c3461d69e26 fwd="-" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=1732
2014-10-12T06:47:05.367842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" host=mmmm.herokuapp.com request_id=2938c0d1-62ad-4e43-acdb-1dc23588754f fwd="-" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=173
```

My Procfile contains :

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/kosh -Dhttp.port=$PORT -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the file from "Messages" to "messages" (with a lowercase m) had fix the problem. On my Windows side file was case insensitive, on heroku side, in an Unix world, file names were case sensitives. Play framework seem to look for file in lower case at heroku.

Comment: I just want to point out that this is indeed the way to go, the documentation also uses lower case: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaI18N#Externalizing-messages

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I migth have been mistaken when I created my files with the fact that the function start with an uppercase @Messages(). My bad. I think in the old days, I just copy paste the function to name the file...